# Regex to extract string after a "|"

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to regex. I am trying to extract string post a `"|"`. I have below type of string.

```
(String1) | (string2 string3)
```

I want to extract values of `string2 and string3` using `C#`.

I have used below regex, however it didn't worked.

1. `@"*|(\S)"`
2. `@"(?<=\|)(.*?)"`

Comment: Don't need a regex, using Split() and take the second array element.

Comment: do you mean you want to match the strings between the parenthesis after the `|` ?

Comment: Learn a little about ``Split()``.

Comment: `string result = source.Substring(source.IndexOf('|') + 1).Trim(' ', '(', ')');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*With regex*, you can use

```cs
var text = "(String1) | (string2 string3)";
var result = Regex.Match(text, @"\|\s*\(([^()]*)\)")?.Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(result); // => string2 string3
```

See also the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%7C%5Cs*%5C%28%28%5B%5E%28%29%5D*%29%5C%29&i=%28String1%29%20%7C%20%28string2%20string3%29). The `\|\s*\(([^()]*)\)` pattern matches a `|` char, then zero or more whitespaces, `(`, then captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars other than parentheses, and then matches a `)` char.

*Without regex*, if the string is always like this, you may split with space+`|`+space, get the second item and trim out `(` and `)`:

```cs
var result2 = text.Split(new[] {" | "}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Trim(new[] {'(', ')'});
Console.WriteLine(result2); // => string2 string3
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/ndSy3I).

Answer (score 1):

This can help you.
Use `Split()` method, which return an array and take the second element [1].

```
  public string ExtractString(string str)
    {
        return str.Split("|")[1].Trim('(',')');
    }
```

Have a good day :)